# I’m a 16 year old girl

Tags: home-exercise

My thighs are a tad bit heavy but my calves and lower part are perfect. However, I have fat deposition on my inner side of the knees.

Any way to get rid of that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Fitness SE! It sounds like you're asking if you can reduce fat on a single part of your body. The linked question has some good answers on that. If you feel I've made a mistake, and your question is fundamentally different, feel free to edit the question, and it will be put through a re-opening process.